# Redirecting causes url to change and won't redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, redirect

I've made a redirect in a htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /example.com/oldAddress http://www.example.com/newAddress.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

But it generates this url:

```
http://www.example.com/newAddress.php?redirect=1
```

so it causes a 404 error. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldAddress http://www.example.com/newAddress.php? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` in the end will target any existing query string.